# Tornar o preenchimento do campo input text obrigatorio se o checkbox correspondente a ele for selecionado

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

[A solução foi com Javascript, colocarei no final do código]
Galera, esse meu código funciona perfeitamente, quando um checkbox é selecionado o input relacionado a ele aparece mas se eu não preencho ele e coloco pra incluir o formulário, acaba dando erro. Então eu preciso que para cada checkbox selecionado, o campo input relacionado a ele seja de preenchimento obrigatorio. Alguém poderia me dar este help?

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Possui redes sociais?</label>
                                <div id="quais_redes" class="col-sm-10">
                                    @foreach($redes as $item)
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" id="quais_redes" type="checkbox" name="quais_redes[]"
                                          value={{$item->red_id}} @if(is_array(old('quais_redes')) &&
                                        in_array($item->red_id,old('quais_redes'))) checked @endif>
                                        {{$item->red_id}} - {{$item->red_nome}}
                                    </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                        @if(isset($error) and isset($error['quais_redes']))
                                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                @foreach ($error['quais_redes'] as $e)
                                                    <li>{{$e}}</li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                        @endif


                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                                    <label for="facebook">Qual o seu Facebook?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rede_facebook" id="rede_facebook" data-label="rede_facebook" value="{{ old('rede_facebook') }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                                    <label for="instagram">Qual o seu Instagram?</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rede_instagram" id="rede_instagram" data-label="rede_instagram" value="{{ old('rede_instagram') }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                                    <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Twitter?</label>twitter
                                    <input type="text" name="rede_twitter" class="form-control" id="rede_twitter" data-label="rede_twitter" value="{{ old('rede_twitter') }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                                    <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Telegram?</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="rede_telegram" class="form-control" id="rede_telegram" data-label="rede_telegram" value="{{ old('rede_telegram') }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
                                    <label for="twitter">Qual o seu Whatsapp?</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="rede_whatsapp" class="form-control" id="rede_whatsapp" data-label="rede_whatsapp" value="{{ old('rede_whatsapp') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

```
    const campo1 = document.getElementById('Facebook')
    const campo2 = document.getElementById('rede_Facebook')
    const campo3 = document.getElementById('Instagram')
    const campo4 = document.getElementById('rede_Instagram')
    const campo5 = document.getElementById('Twitter')
    const campo6 = document.getElementById('rede_Twitter')
    const campo7 = document.getElementById('Telegram')
    const campo8 = document.getElementById('rede_Telegram')
    const campo9 = document.getElementById('Whatsapp')
    const campo10 = document.getElementById('rede_Whatsapp')
    const campo11 = document.getElementById('leciona_sim')
    const campo12 = document.getElementById('leciona_nome_inst')
    const btn_sub = document.getElementById('btn-submit');

    // console.log(campo1,campo2, btn_sub)
    btn_sub.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if(campo1.checked && !$("#rede_Facebook").val()) {
            alert('Preencha o campo Qual o seu Facebook');
            document.getElementById('rede_Facebook').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
            }
        if(campo3.checked && !$("#rede_Instagram").val()){
            alert('Preencha o campo Qual o seu Instagram');
            document.getElementById('rede_Instagram').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if(campo5.checked && !$("#rede_Twitter").val()){
            alert('Preencha o campo Qual o seu Twitter');
            document.getElementById('rede_Twitter').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if(campo7.checked && !$("#rede_Telegram").val()){
            alert('Preencha o campo Qual o seu Telegram');
            document.getElementById('rede_Telegram').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if(campo9.checked && !$("#rede_Whatsapp").val()){
            alert('Preencha o campo Qual o seu Whatsapp');
            document.getElementById('rede_Whatsapp').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Juliana, você consegue realizar isso utilizando o required_if do Validation

Por exemplo:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'input_text_relacionado' => 'required_if:checkbox_relacionado,1'
]);
```

No caso o 1 seria o value que está no checkbox

Comment: Valeu pela resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Não acredito ser a melhor solução, mas você poderia adicionar o 'required' via javascript, no caso como você deve estar utilizando um javascript para tornar visível o input selecionado, então dentro do código colocaria essa linha:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-input").required = true;
```

esse código seria para cada input que vc tem, o problema é que torna-se necessário fazer o processo inverso caso seja possível desmarcar o checkbox, senão ele vai ficar pedindo pra você digitar em um input que não está mais ali.

O próprio laravel tem uma documentação sobre as validações, acho que você tentou utilizar, mas eu não teria conhecimento pra te dizer se dá pra fazer esse dinamismo de validar somente se o checkbox estiver selecionando.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, Daniel!